# Partial Upgrade removes signed GRUB EFI and breaks Secure Boot

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, uefi, secure-boot

Software Updater wants me to do a partial upgrade, and the list of changes shows that it removes the grub-efi-signed package and replaces it with the regular unsigned grub-efi. I tested this in a VM, and it broke Secure Boot support.

Clean installations are also broken with the latest 14.04 LTS ISO. It fails during installation of the signed GRUB EFI package and crashes ubiquity. Only workaround is to install without an Internet connection.

So far I've just installed updates with the Continue option without doing the partial upgrade, but it pops up every time the updater runs. Is this going to get fixed? Why is it happening? Are they shuffling around some packages on the repositories?

Comment: Please [file a bug report](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) about this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is the same problem I filed a [bug report](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2-signed/+bug/1524980) on earlier today.  It has been fixed and once I manually updated `grub-efi-amd64-signed` all is well.

A [similar problem reported in June](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2-signed/+bug/1469995) was claimed to be a "process escape"...apparently it escaped again.

Comment: Ah, I ran another update check, and it seems to have a bunch of updates for the signed kernel images. All is indeed well.